# Having trouble adding custom Component in tooolbox

Tags: vb.net

How to add a custom component to my toolbox.

I have a class that inherits Panel. I want to add this to my toolbox.

I followed these steps:

1. Right Click on Toolbox (On general tab )
2. Choose Items
3. In the .NET Components Tab, I can't
   find my Class.

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile your project first.  Once it is compiled, it should appear in that list and you can use it from then on.  If you make changes to it again and want to use the newly added features, compile it again so the designer can include the new stuff.